# How can I set error message on multiple fields?

Tags: android

So I have a register screen with many fields. If the user clicks on register button and one or multiple fields are empty I want to show an error on those fileds.

RegistrationActivity:

```
private void onRegisterButtonClick() {
    String name =nameEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    String email =emailEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    String password =passwordEditText.getText().toString().trim();
    String phoneNumber = phoneNumberEditText.getText().toString().trim();

    registrationPresenter.register(name, email, password, phoneNumber);
}

private void showEmptyFieldError(){
   nameEditText.showError("This field can not be empty");
}
```

RegistrationPresenter:

```
 public void register(String name, String email, String password, String phoneNumber) {
    if (name.isEmpty() || email.isEmpty() || password.isEmpty() || phoneNumber.isEmpty()) {
        registrationView.showEmptyFieldError();
    }
}
```

How is implemented now is not what I want because it shows error only on "name" field. How can I check if fields are empty and show error only on those ones in easiest way?

Comment: not sure if this is the best solution. Use multiple if to validate the values.

Comment: ya you must have to check for the each input field values.

Answer (score 2):

You can show error on any field using this..

```
    private void onRegisterButtonClick() {
        String name =nameEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        String email =emailEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        String password =passwordEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        String phoneNumber = phoneNumberEditText.getText().toString().trim();

        if (name.isEmpty()) {
            nameEditText.setError("Name cannot be empty");
        }

        if (email.isEmpty()) {
            emailEditText.setError("Email cannot be empty");
        }

        if (password.isEmpty()) {
            passwordEditText.setError("Password cannot be empty");
        }

        if (!name.isEmpty() && !email.isEmpty() && !password.isEmpty()) {
            registrationPresenter.register(name, email, password, phoneNumber);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on @Ali Ahmed answer, you can also try `else if` conditions.

```
private void onRegisterButtonClick() {
        String name = nameEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        String email = emailEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        String password = passwordEditText.getText().toString().trim();
        String phoneNumber = phoneNumberEditText.getText().toString().trim();

        if (name.isEmpty()) {
            nameEditText.setError("Name cannot be empty");
        } else if (email.isEmpty()) {
            emailEditText.setError("Email cannot be empty");
        } else if (password.isEmpty()) {
            passwordEditText.setError("Password cannot be empty");
        } else {
            registrationPresenter.register(name, email, password, phoneNumber);
        }
    }
```

So if name is empty, error message will display only on name field, after fill name field, if email is empty, error message will display only on email and so on...

And if all fields are filled, then else part will execute.

Comment: yes we do that using **elseif...elseif...elseif** _@Chirag_ you should mention this  in comment part of _@Ali Ahmed_ no need to write whole answer just because of **elseif...elseif...elseif**

Comment: he said he want to show error on multiple fields.. by your method it will show error on only first field which is empty. not on all fields.